# 404 error empty CSS file

Tags: css, http-status-code-404

My CSS files do exist. They just don't have anything inside - they are empty.

Chrome however, show 404 errors for my CSS files.
[image]
[image]

Putting some dummy code e.g. comments in a CSS file makes the error goes away.

Any idea what went wrong for me?

**Updates:**
The document root of the website is `/var/www/html/niuniu/`.

Some of you mentions permission issue but how does it explain the issue when I put in some comments in the CSS file and the error went away - no changes in permission?

I'm using Prestashop but I don't believe that has to do with the issue here.

Comment: Is your site's root folder `/var/www/html/` or `/var/www/html/niuniu/`?

Comment: can't replicate the error... you might have to recheck your filepath?

Comment: The server process may need to own the files.  Depending on the server, you may need `chown -R www-data /var/www/html/niuniu/`

Comment: the latter @ultranaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is just how Chrome's Developer Tools and Firebug report empty CSS file. This is not a real error that can break my website.

Comment: I ran to the same issue, however for me this error was present only when the server was deployed to a Kubernetes cluster. If I ran the server locally, I got 200 with empty content. Rip 2 hours from my life -__-